# How do I fix this c000021a with additional info so it can start to windows again?

Tags: windows-10

[image]

I brought to other place and it works fine.

I brought to my home and I got this problem.

Can't get to windows. But can get far enough to command prompt for me to get rid bitlocker and stuff.

Comment: A technician around 1.5 km than me. He connect different keyboard and mouse. I will try connecting non USB keyboard and mouse too

Answer (score 3):

> How do I fix this c000021a with additional info so it can start to windows again?

The behavior you describe is a known issue with KB5021233.

> 1. You will need to enter Windows Recovery Environment. If your device has not automatically started up into WinRE, please see Entry points
>    into WinRE.
> 2. Select the Troubleshoot button.
> 3. Select the "Start recovery, troubleshooting, and diagnostic tools" button.
> 4. Select the "Advanced Options" button.
> 5. Select the "Command Prompt" button and wait for your device to restart, if needed.
> 6. Your device should restart to a Command Prompt window. You might need to sign into your device with your password before getting to the
>    Command Prompt window.
> 7. Run the following command (Important: If Windows is not installed to C:\windows you will need to modify the command to your
>    environment): *xcopy C:\windows\system32\drivers\hidparse.sys
>    C:\windows\system32\hidparse.sys*
> 8. Once the previous command completes, type: exit
> 9. Select the "Continue" button.
> 10. Windows should now start up as expected.

Microsoft already released a fixed for this issue, although the workaround must be performed, regardless if you encounter the issue.

> Resolution: This issue was resolved in KB5022282. This update should prevent the issue from occurring. Windows devices in which this issue has already occurred will still need to follow the workaround above.

Source: [You might receive an error (0xc000021a) with a blue screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-22h2#2986msgdesc)

Comment: As for the reason I know the issue is caused y that update, the effected file hidparse.sys, is a critical file used with USB devices. If you are not a system administrator on the machine you should avoid performing these steps yourself and have your IT department fix the issue themselves.

Answer (score -1):

I finally got it fixed.

My bro took out the USB and somehow it works.

So the wifi USB may be faulty. But it's now working fine. So I am not sure.

It's working now.